# Determine how long the server was off, when it off and when it back on

Tags: server, monitoring, system-monitor, uptime

Is there an application i can install on my server so as to know (be notified ) that server has gone off and for how long it was off and also know the time it went on again.

Am trying nagios but cant figure out that option. 
Better still  an application to indicate network usage by graph between give time intervals and store logs for reference

Comment: You can use `vnstat` to monitor your network traffic over time.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is in the terminal just type the following:

```
uptime
```

It shows you the current time and the very next thing is the duration (for how long your system has been running).